# Динозаврик гугла

Tags: c++

Можно ли написать на С++ динозаврика гугловского? (это который появляется,когда нет интернет-соединения)

Может быть где-то есть открытый код на эту игру?..

Comment: можно написать, но оно вам надо

Comment: да,надо,но меня уже успели напугать,что с графикой запарюсь на плюсах

Comment: Если брать готовые библиотечки, не запаритесь. Например https://github.com/libSDL2pp/libSDL2pp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да, можно.
Код есть в репозитории chromium: [T-Rex runner](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/neterror/resources/offline.js?q=offline.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)

Comment: Ваш ответ - это реализация на JS, а автор спросил про C++.

Comment: @Aid было два вопроса, на оба я ответил. Во втором, про код, о C++ речь не шла.

Comment: Очевидно, автор подразумевал исходники на плюсах.

Comment: По мотивам обсуждения в чате "за что плюсуем" поясняю. Возможно, автор и имел ввиду код только на плюсах, но я считаю, что для нормального программиста вполне подходит следующий вариант ответа "кода на плюсах с большой вероятностью нет, в хромиуме используется js -- поэтому могу предоставить ссылку на код из репозитория хромиума". Подозреваю, что если вдруг уже кто-то портировал этот на плюсы (ну, вдруг) то можно будет и переставить галку, но значимости этого ответа это не умаляет.

Answer (score 0):

Ну есть несколько вариантов:

Windows Forms и C++/CLI. Помещаете на форму PictureBox и отрисовываете на нем свою игру.

Можно использовать какие-либо библиотеки для разработки игр, например SFML.

Возможно, есть какие-то среды программирования для разработки игр на С++